# Is there a way to know if a server is using ssh public key or password?

Tags: passwords, public-key-infrastructure, ssh

I am wondering is there a way for an attacker through finger printing to find out whether a server is using public-key versus password authentication method for establishing an SSH connection?

Comment: Try this `ssh user@localhost -vv`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running `ssh -vvv host`, at some point, you will see something like:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
```

The first two lines describe what methods are offered by the server and the last one is what is offered by your client (`PreferredAuthentications` option from `ssh_config`). From this log (to my Raspberry Pi), you can see that server is able to accept `publickey,password` authentication methods. This list might also differ for different users or for different source addresses (`AuthenticationMethods` options in `Match` block in server `sshd_config`), but it does not say that the authentication can succeed (eg. the user have a password or public key, nor whether the `root` login is allowed is you try `root` login).

Most of the servers will give you this "fingerprint". Some of them will give you just `publickey`, which says they do not accept passwords. Having server accepting passwords and not accepting pubkey is very rare.

In short, you are able to gain some information as described above, but it is not much useful in most of the cases.

Comment: Thank Jakuje! I was wondering whether only having password  can be count as a insecurity for a sever?

Comment: It depends on which password. But generally yes. If you don't have any detection of brute-force attacks.

Comment: Thanks @Jakuje. Do you have an idea how can I run it via a python script? I tried subprocesses but it always requires password whereas with shell it does not